# Boundaries of movement fragment in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

How to set the boundaries of movement of fragment in viewpager?

I have two fragments. ViewPager showing first fragment at start. When I slide right viewpager showing second fragment, and i want show a part of fist fragment at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mPager.setPageMargin(-100);
```

This method can emulate border movement.

You can also use:

```
mPager.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```